# Updating one table's column in SQL Server from another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of measurements from weather stations, with station names (in Hebrew):

[image]

I also have created a table of those weather stations with their latitudes and longitudes:

[image]

I've written a query that should update the first table with the lat/longs from the second, but it's not working:

```
update t1
set t1.MeasurementLat = t2.Latitude,
    t1.MeasurementLong = t2.Longitude
from [dbo].[Measurements] as t1
inner join [dbo].[StationCoords] as t2 on t1.StationName like t2.Station
```

I think there is a problem with the way the station name is being read, and perhaps something to do with encoding, because this query brings back an empty result, too:

```
SELECT TOP (5) *
FROM [dbo].[Measurements]
WHERE [StationName] = 'אריאל מכללה';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `=` instead of `like`.  And your example names are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example names are not the same.  Perhaps this will work:

```
update m
    set MeasurementLat = sc.Latitude,
        MeasurementLong = sc.Longitude
    from dbo.[Measurements] m join
         dbo.[StationCoords] sc
         on m.StationName like sc.Station + '%';
```

Comment: Which example names are not the same?

Comment: It works, but I am not sure what I was doing wrong-can you explain?

Comment: @BorisK . . . `Station` and `Station Name` are not the same.  `LIKE` with no wildcards is a lot like `=`.

Comment: Station in StationCoords is the same as StationName in Measurements, though. I just used these two entries as examples, they're not the same station. Perhaps it was the wildcard that made the difference?

Comment: @BorisK . . . It would seem then that the wildcard made the difference.